# Get the text entered in the text box on loss of focus with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

How can I get the value entered in the textbox below?

```
<tr>
    <td class="TextBold" >1.</td>
    <td class="TextBold" >Content for Question 1:</td>
    <td class="TextBold" >
      <input name="ctl00$DefaultContent$ctl2" type="text" class="TextNormal" />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

This gives me the *name* of the textbox:

```
var idT = $("td:contains('1.')").next().next().children().eq(0).attr('name');
```

Now I would like to write function which will give the value entered in the textbox.

Something like:

```
 $('input[name^=ctl00$DefaultContent$ctl2]').blur(function () {
        alert($(this).val());    
    });
```

This worked for me:

```
 $('input[name="' + idT + '"]').blur(function () {
            alert($(this).val());    
        });
```

Comment: You have to "escape" the `$` see my updated JSfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('input[name="ctl00$DefaultContent$ctl2"]').val()` should give you the value of the text field but is "ctl00$DefaultContent$ctl2" really the name?

See this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sepbg/)**

Comment: This is dynamically generated control. When I looked into the source code this is how the name of the input control looks like.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input[name=' + id+ ']').blur(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Notice that your's var name is `id` but it's value is name... why?

I would change to:

```
var id = $("td:contains('1.')").next().next().children().eq(0).attr('id');

$('#' + id).blur(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXq8h/3/) example

You have to `"escape"` the `$` with `\\$`to use it with jquery selectors.

Comment: gdoron Thank you. I tried the solution you posted but nothing happens on the blur()

Comment: @BumbleBee, Did you get an id\name with your selector? the problem is probably there.

Comment: @BumbleBee, Make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see where the problem is

Comment: I am able to get the name with the selector

Comment: @BumbleBee.Did you select the `id` or the `name`? don't get confuse.

Comment: As it is dynamically generated control I see only the 'name' but not the 'ID'

Comment: @BumbleBee Added JsFiddle example

Comment: @BumbleBee. You have to "escape" the '$' I updated the JSFiddler.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6838/discussion-between-gdoron-and-bumblebee)